# docker image build fails at RUN pip install -r requirements.txt in a Flask app

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have a Flask application with the following **requirements.txt**

```
chalice
matplotlib
sklearn
numpy
scipy
pandas
flask
flask_restful
```

and the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
WORKDIR /project
ADD . /project
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Running the command `docker image build -t clf_test .`
generates the following error:

```
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It seems that the matplotlib can't get installed for some reason.
Running the `pip install -r requirements.txt` locally doesn't produce any errors

Comment: You are including the least useful part of the4 error message. What happened on the previous lines?

Comment: Hey! Please provide the entire output of your build command if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` must be built from source, and compiling it requires a number of supporting libraries as well as a functioning C compiler. You can figure out what these are and install them so that it builds properly...

...or you can just base your `Dockerfile` on the non-alpine `python:3.6.1` image and then `apt-get install python3-matplotlib` before installing your other requirements. E.g., this builds without errors:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
WORKDIR /project
ADD . /project
RUN apt update; apt-get -y install python3-matplotlib
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```